# rails 5 Uncaught Reference Error when trying to load google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I am getting the following error in my chrome console when trying to load a dynamic google map using google-maps-for-rails gem.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: handler is not defined
```

[image]

> **My locations controller index action (where map is to be loaded):**

```
  def index
    @locations = Location.all

    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@locations) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude
    end
  end
```

> **The various scripts required:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE" async defer></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
</script>
```

> **The Map Div:**

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
```

not sure where I'm going wrong here, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

cheers.

Comment: Where is come from the variable `handler`? That's your error, it's pretty clear, the variable `handler` is not defined. Here is nothing about Rails and Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `handler` variable:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
```

So the code should be:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE" async defer></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
</script>
```